# Unable to Add UI elements on top of AGSMapView

Tags: ios, swift, arcgis-runtime

I have an app that I'm trying to migrate from Google Maps to ArcGIS maps because I need to use the maps offline.
I'm using the ArcGIS iOS 100.6 SDK and am trying to place a UIbutton on top of AGSMapView. In the View Controller "MapView" and the UIButton are under "View". The UIbutton is not a subview of MapView. I also have three other elements that should overlay the map that I hide and unhide using "isHidden = true/false" and these cannot be displayed either. The app is written in Swift 4.2 and I'm using Xcode 10.3.

```
Here is the view in the view controller:

View
   Safe Area
   Btn Satellite Toggle (outlet name: "btnSatelliteToggle")
   View Mark Location
   View Verify Location
   View Pic Detail
   MapView
   Constraints

This is the code where I show the map and try to add the button on top:

let viewMap = AGSMapView(frame: .zero)
viewMap.map = AGSMap(basemapType: .navigationVector,
                                         latitude:   currentLocation.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.longitude,
                                         levelOfDetail: zoomLevel)
viewMap.graphicsOverlays.add(overlay)
viewMap.touchDelegate = self
view = viewMap
view.bringSubviewToFront(btnSatelliteToggle)
```

The map is displayed along with the graphics overlay, but I am unable to show any UI elements on top of the map.  This works fine with Google maps, but not with ArcGIS maps.
How do I get these UI elements to be displayed on top of the AGSMapView generated map?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you adding the button to view first or where are you adding the button?
You're setting view to be viewMap.
looks like when you set view = mapView, you no longer have the button. as mapView is no longer a subview but the view itself

Comment: I've tried a lot of different ways to add the button.  I have tried adding the button first and then adding the map as a subview.  In that case the mapView area is gray, shows the ESRI copyright message at the bottom of the screen and the button is displayed, but the map never appears.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your MapView is at the top of the view hierarchy and thus obscuring its sibling views.

Try rearranging the view hierarchy to place the MapView at the bottom:

```
View
   Safe Area
   MapView
   Btn Satellite Toggle (outlet name: "btnSatelliteToggle")
   View Mark Location
   View Verify Location
   View Pic Detail
   Constraints
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I had previously tried this with the same result.  See my post below as I just solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just solved this.  Here is the updated code that works:

```
viewMap.map = AGSMap(basemapType: .navigationVector,
                                         latitude: currentLocation.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.longitude,
                                         levelOfDetail: zoomLevel)
viewMap.graphicsOverlays.add(overlay)
viewMap.touchDelegate = self
```

I removed:

`Setting AGSMapView(frame: .zero)`

as this prevented the map from being displayed in MapView.

Also, by not setting a view (thus using the default view controller "view") all siblings are available for display and can be controlled via "isHidden."